# improve ivy's completions

Tags: completion, ivy

When I do `M-x package install`, (with a space between the words) I get:

[image]

I'd like the "package-install" option to be prioritized over "package-menu-mark-install". What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: Pure `ivy` with default settings is showing `package-install` as first match. So you have something else interfering.

Comment: I was using emacs-ng with emacs-28 (beta version). downgraded to Emacs 27 (without emacs-ng) which resolved the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.